# Oracle Apex - Display Items based on number of values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a regular link on an Interactive Report:

[image: my IR]

That links sends the Deal Number information into a different page where the user will be able to update all product information.
As per customer request, I need to use items. Issue is, that I need to show one textfield item per Product, so for example:

If Peter is selected (as per my snap above), I would need to show 2 textfield Items, one for Product 'ABC' and another for Product 'XYZ'.

If John is selected, I would need to show 3 textfield Items, one for 'Product1', one for 'Product2' and another for 'Product3'.

Is there a way to achieve this dynamic display of items?
If so, how can I make Item 1 to show Product1 info, Item 2 to show Product2 info and so on?

Thanks

Comment: take employee name as REQUEST, prepare url with it. on target page, set your items attributes upon these request values. for instance; item a => if request = value (value = Peter, Parker, May) item b => if request = value (value = John, Peter)

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of routes you can take, each one has it's pros and cons.

**1. the APEX_ITEM API**

This is an API that renders apex items, as part of a sql query or in a static  region with pl/sql source (not tested that last option)

Pro:

- a lot of flexibility

Cons:

- Look and feel is "old" - doesn't look anything like the modern page items that exist in the universal theme and you're stuck with that old look and feel. Lots of hardcoded pl/sql.

**2. A fixed number of pre-created items.**

Create a number of items and populate only the ones you need, eg P1_PRODUCT1_NAME, P1_PRODUCT2_NAME, ... .If you only need a single product then you're populate only P1_PRODUCT1_NAME, else you'd use as much as you need. With server sided conditions you hide/show the ones not needed/needed

Pro:

- All the bells & whistles for look and feel you have in "normal" forms

Cons:

- Can't render more products than what you created items for in your page. What if you create fields for 10 products but you need 11 ?

**3. Interactive Grid.**

I know "the customer wants items" but this component is specifically written for this purpose. I'd definitely consider this as an option - maybe you can make the customer change his mind.

Pro:

- Very modern apex component, highly configurable. Check the interactive grid cookbook for a ton of advanced examples.

Cons:

- Not items - this is tabular form/spreadsheet layout. Not all end users like them as a form of data entry.

Comment: thanks Koen, appreciate it!