# How can I make a dynamic form with APEX Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm wondering how I can make a dynamic page with APEX.

By dynamic I need to make a form which will have checkboxes for each line of a table. So if the table has 10 rows I need 10 checkboxes to be selected.

I was going down the APEX_ITEM route however that is deprecated....oh well

### Thanks

Comment: A very similar question was asked a couple of hours before yours: have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186423/oracle-apex-display-items-based-on-number-of-values)

Answer (score 0):

`APEX_ITEM` is deprecated? Since when? It is not, as far as I can tell.

---

I'd suggest you to use **interactive grid**. It will display as many rows as you want (10 in your case), while item type can be set to "checkbox" so you'd either check it (or not).

---

If you want to do it *dynamically*, then one option is to create a **stored procedure** which would "draw" the page using `htp.p` calls. You'd, I presume, have a loop (because you have to create as many page elements as there are rows in a table - 10, you said).

Region type is then **PL/SQL dynamic content**.

Does it work? Yes, I've use it occasionally. Is it worth the pain (if compared to interactive grid)? Can't tell, it is up to you.